# mbfpdf does not work

Tags: php, pear, fpdf

I try to make a pdf file which has some japanese character. However, the output file is some strange character. I use mbfpdf instead of fpdf.

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fpdf/font/');
require('fpdf/mbfpdf.php');


$pdf=& new MBFPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddMBFont(GOTHIC ,'EUC-JP');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont(GOTHIC,'',20);
$pdf->Write(20,'日本語');
$pdf->Output('test.pdf');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line inside the head tags

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If you are getting garbage texts after executing mysql queries, execute both the below queries first.

```
SET NAMES utf8
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to ISO-8859-1 with utf8_decode() (some inaccuracy):

```
    $str = utf8_decode($str);
```

or if iconv extension is available (preferred):

```
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);
```